# Troubleshooting 'grep: line too long'

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file that must have one or more "too long" lines in it: when I `grep` it I get

```
grep: line too long
```

There are [a number of posts on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=grep%3A+line+too+long) recommending alternatives, none of which are working for me.  Is there some way for me to identify and eliminate the long lines in the file, or a strategy for breaking the file into smaller files to try and isolate the too long line(s)?

Here is a sample of the commands I've tried based upon the other posts:

```
$ cat myFile | grep -no 'myText' > out.txt
$ grep 'myText' myFile > out.txt
```

The file's size is 3367005608, which is probably only relevant as I was trying to use `zgrep` initially, but ran into the same issues.  I get the following error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=myFile FNR=1) fatal: set_record: databuf: can't allocate 2147483648 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)
```

when using `awk`

```
awk '/myText/' myFile > out.txt
```

Comment: I don't know that it would be any better - it might have similar line length limitations - but you could try `awk '/myText/' myFile` as an alternative to `grep`... Also, for troubleshooting purposes: `awk 'length() > 1000 { print NR, length(); }` will give you a line number and length for any lines over the specified threshhold...

Comment: @twalberg I've updated my question -- `awk` seems to have an issue with the line or file size, too.

Comment: I'd guess your file contains no newlines so neither awk nor grep can work one line at a time but instead has to try to read the whole file into memory. Is there some other character in the file that can be used by awk to separate it into "records"?

Comment: @EdMorton the file is a `gunzip`ped `gz` log file that _should be_ human readable (just huge).  When `tail`ing it looks fine, but when `less`ing it I'm prompted `"myFile" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?`.  I can open it but the top is all `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^`s.  The bottom is ok.  So it appears that this is due to file corruption.  I was using tail  before so didn't realize that corruption had occurred.

Comment: My plan was to split the file and start eliminating parts that were corrupt.  Ran into `split: xae: No space left on device`, though, so I'll have to see about getting more space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stripping out all null bytes first from your file:

```
tr -d '\000' < fileWithNulls > noNulls
```

And then try running your grep or awk with `noNulls` file.

Comment: I got kicked off of the share since my file was too large, but I got a memory error when I tried your solution.  I'm trying to secure more space and then will give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava -- this worked like a champ once I procured enough space and looked at the man page for `tr` and realized `<` and `>` were significant, not just used to denote boilerplate :)

Comment: You're most welcome, I used it long time back to trip my log file from these null bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a binary file, the occurance of a null byte `\0` is usually more common that the occurance of a newline `\n`. So you could break on null bytes instead

```
grep -z 'myText' myFile
```

or perhaps all control characters

```
tr '[:cntrl:]' '\n' < myFile | grep myText
```

Comment: Thank you @StevenPenny.  Going off @EdMorton's probing above I found that the file appears to be corrupt.  Both of your suggestions and `tr '[:cntrl:]' '\0' < myFile | grep myText` result in the `grep: line too long` message.